# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Bug? Two factor Authentication (2FA)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

After enabling 2FA, it still shows the setup buttons? (ASP.NET Core 2.1)

See screenshot below

[image]

Code (standard code unmodified)

```
@page
@model TwoFactorAuthenticationModel
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Two-factor authentication (2FA)";
}

@Html.Partial("_StatusMessage", Model.StatusMessage)
<h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
@if (Model.Is2faEnabled)
{
    if (Model.RecoveryCodesLeft == 0)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>You have no recovery codes left.</strong>
            <p>You must <a asp-page="./GenerateRecoveryCodes">generate a new set of recovery codes</a> before you can log in with a recovery code.</p>
        </div>
    }
    else if (Model.RecoveryCodesLeft == 1)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>You have 1 recovery code left.</strong>
            <p>You can <a asp-page="./GenerateRecoveryCodes">generate a new set of recovery codes</a>.</p>
        </div>
    }
    else if (Model.RecoveryCodesLeft <= 3)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <strong>You have @Model.RecoveryCodesLeft recovery codes left.</strong>
            <p>You should <a asp-page="./GenerateRecoveryCodes">generate a new set of recovery codes</a>.</p>
        </div>
    }

    if (Model.IsMachineRemembered)
    {
        <form method="post" style="display: inline-block">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Forget this browser</button>
        </form>
    }
    <a asp-page="./Disable2fa" class="btn btn-default">Disable 2FA</a>
    <a asp-page="./GenerateRecoveryCodes" class="btn btn-default">Reset recovery codes</a>
}

<h5>Authenticator app</h5>
@if (!Model.HasAuthenticator)
{
    <a id="enable-authenticator" asp-page="./EnableAuthenticator" class="btn btn-default">Add authenticator app</a>
}
else
{
    <a id="enable-authenticator" asp-page="./EnableAuthenticator" class="btn btn-default">Setup authenticator app</a>
    <a id="reset-authenticator" asp-page="./ResetAuthenticator" class="btn btn-default">Reset authenticator app</a>
}

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm tired, blind, or something, but `it still shows the setup buttons?` - why should it not? Do you mean that `EnableAuthenticator` is visible in both cases? maybe that's the same route, but it **does** something different?

Comment: I think you mixed up your Add and Setup button. Because from you code it is correct, that the setup button is displayed

Comment: I'm confused? In every case, it always shows in both chases where Model.HasAuthenticator is true, (it is always true even if I disable the Authenticator it still true?)

Comment: I debugged it "HasAuthenticator" is always true! Authenticator enabled or disable HasAuthenticator is true!

Comment: HasAuthenticator = await _userManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user) != null; <-- this code, its always true, but it shouldnt be!